# Getting started with c++ in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I decided to learn c++ but I don't know how to get started. I don't know what type of project should I open. Also I am using SoloLearn to learn c++.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but you can try to write C/C++ code in Code::Blocks IDE.
If i'm not wrong, SoloLearn provides a tutorial on how to download it.
SoloLearn is a good app for learning the simplest basics, from printing "Hello world!" to work with files.. I was using it when i learned C++.
In Code::Blocks website, select that download link that contains the setup with CB and MinGW compiler..
If you don't want to use Code::Blocks use Netbeans but i don't know it very well.
First of all. You must configure Netbeans for C/C++/Fortran
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html
If you already did it, create a project!
Go to File > New Project and select C/C++ Category.
You will have several choices of type of C++ project and so select C/C++ Application.
For next steps just use default settings.
Netbeans saves the project in a logical folder..
So you won't have the project file but a folder.
And in it, there are your files (for example, main.cpp, config files, Makefile, etc).
I hope to be useful to you!
Good work